# Best Practices: Save Empty Fields as null or omit Field Completely and Manage Missing Fields in Code?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

Given collection that will have 50+ million documents,
and every document will have a maximum number of fields (shown in option a)
What is the best practice for dealing with fields that can be null/sparse?

a)Is it better to save every document with the same fields and empty fields as null?

```
{
  "_id": "54ca5b234d2dfeba4f9ab613",
  "person_id": 1,
  "person_name": "Bob",
  "office_phone": null,
  "description": "This is where the description is entered",
  "technical_description": null

}
```

b)Or is it better to leave out the fields if they have no data?

```
{
  "_id": "54ca5b234d2dfeba4f9ab613",
  "person_id": 1,
  "person_name": "Bob",
  "description": "This is where the description is entered",
}
```

What are the considerations in keeping fields with null in terms of `mongod` ram usage and performance? 
Essentially omitting fields that are empty would create a situation where the application needs to implement a way to check if fields exist.
What considerations should there be at the application level if delegating this "empty check" to code? Is it heavy?
Will omitting fields in the collection if they are empty just delegate the heaviness to the client code layer?

Comment: I suggest keeping it in so you can parse consistently without needing to check (assuming all fields will be in the same order every time). That's just personal preference. My more logical answer would be to not pre-maturly optimize. Find which one suits your application better. Profile your application

Comment: You say null, but I see them absent in your extracts. This can be dealt with easily with JSON Schema.

Comment: @fge He's referring to `"office_phone": null`; he's not sure if he should leave that out, since it's value is null, or if he should leave it in. At least that's what I'm understanding from all this

Comment: @VinceEmigh OK, I didn't read the question fully. There is also the question however of how many of those 50M+ documents are supposed to be in memory at any point in time. Somehow I doubt that it is all 50 millions of them.

Comment: @VinceEmigh If I were to search on the collection, can you walk me through how the documents are pushed into ram? Is it that the entire index + the documents referenced by the index are pushed in ram? And is a BasicCursor going to push everything into ram and/or disk if not enough ram? (especially in the case of 50 million documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to leave them null and check for existence of the field. One disadvantage of document databases over relational databases is that a table only has to provide the name of a column one time while each document has to provide the name of every field in that document.

So considering that you have 50 million documents and the field name `technical_description` is approximately 20 characters long, there will be over 1 gigabyte of storage used just to account for that one key name in every document. If half of your documents have the value as `null` then that's at least half of a GB of utterly wasted space.

That space **will** be used in RAM if the document is loaded into memory. When an index is used, the index will be put into memory and then any documents that are sent to the client will need to be put into memory as they are asked for. Usually not all the documents are accessed at one time and MongoDB has built in pagination with a cursor object.

On the other side, I am not well acquainted with how heavy it is in Java to determine that an object does not have a certain field, but it seems like it should be a fairly light operation.